# NSURLSession POST request return HTML webpage code

Tags: html, asp.net, objective-c, post, nsurlsession

I am trying to submit user input to a webpage and then retrieve returned data. This webpage takes a person's name and returns his/her information from a database. I tried to make a POST request when user clicks a button then send user's input to that webpage. But when I print out returned data, it's just the html source code of that webpage, only without javaScript. How can I change/add the below function to get the person's information page? I've spent lots of time but still can't figure it out. Please help me! Thank you!

```
-(void) sendHTTPPost{
NSString* input = nameTextField.text;
//1
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://find.pitt.edu"]];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
//2
NSData* postData = [input dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
//3
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
[req setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[req setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[req setHTTPBody:postData];
//4
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
//5
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:req
                                        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                            // Do something with response data here - convert to JSON, check if error exists, etc....
                                            if(error != nil){
                                                NSLog(@"error:  %@", error);
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                NSLog(@"%@", str);
                                                NSLog(@"response = %@", response);
                                            }
                                        }];

[task resume];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that the POST body is supposed to contain only the value.  Chances are, it should contain

key=value&key2=value2&key3=value3...

where key is the name of the input, and value is the value of that input, in a URL-encoded format.  (See "Encoding URL Data" in [URL Session Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/WorkingwithURLEncoding/WorkingwithURLEncoding.html) for details on how to URL-encode the values.)